# How to create an ElasticSearch query to get this information?

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to query an ElasticSearch index through the Python module and I am pretty unfamiliar with ElasticSearch. Say my index stores pairs of persons and some information about each pair. I wonder how to create an ElasticSearch query which would give me below pair. Basically, I want to get the `some info` field value from the pair where `person1` is named `John White` and a `teacher` and `person2` is named `Sarah Black` and a `doctor`. I want an exact match, not a fuzzy one.

```
"person1": {
    "name": "John White",
    "job": "teacher"

}
"person2": {
    "name": "Sarah Black",
    "job": "doctor"
}
"some info": "blah blah"
```

I tried below query but it gives me pairs where only 1 of the pairs matches the info I ask for, the other person's name/job could be very different. How to get an exact match where both persons' info matches?

```
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
        "must": {
            "bool" : {
                "should": [
                    { "match": { "person1.name": "John White" }},
                    { "match": { "person1.job": "teacher" }}
                  ],
                "should": [
                    { "match": { "person2.name": "Sarah Black" }},
                    { "match": { "person2.job": "doctor" }}
                  ]
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Use `.keyword` for name and job. It will return the exact match. I mean `person1.name.keyword` likewise for the others too.

Comment: it did not resolve the problem. the hit count reduced from 400 to 100, but I still get pairs where only one person's info matches..

Comment: Add your index mapping above.

Comment: I have updated my answer for your use case. Do check and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

Mapping for your index

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "lc_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": ["lowercase"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "person1": {
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "exact": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "normalizer": "lc_normalizer"
              }
            }
          },
          "job": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "person2": {
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "exact": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "normalizer": "lc_normalizer"
              }
            }
          },
          "job": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "some_info": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"match": {
          "person1.name.exact": "john white"
        }},
        {"match": {
          "person2.name.exact": "Sarah Black"
        }},
        { "term": { "person1.job": "teacher"}},
        { "term": { "person2.job": "doctor"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, this works! A followup question: What is the difference between using `term` vs. using `match` with `exact`?

Comment: `Term` is case-sensitive. `Match` query is not case-sensitive. That's the actual difference.